# found no database files-while reading file tex.aux

Tags: bibtex

I am trying to use BibTeX to include reference, when I compile the `test.tex`, it goes well, but when I click the Bibtex in WinEdt 7.0， it says

> 'I have found no database files while reading file test.aux'.

The `.bib` file are in the same folder with `test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
Test citation: \citep{Jag08}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{article}
\end{document}
```

I use the Windows 10, and then modify the name to `article.bib`.

The following is the content of my `.bib`. The path is `C:\Users\wisp\Documents\temp`.

```
 @article{Jag08,
       author = {{de Jager}, O.~C. and {Djannati-Ata{\"i}}, A.},
        title = "{Implications of H.E.S.S. observations of pulsar wind nebulae}",
      journal = {ArXiv e-prints},
    archivePrefix = "arXiv",
       eprint = {0803.0116},
     keywords = {Astrophysics},
         year = 2008,
        month = mar,
       adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2008arXiv0803.0116D},
      adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
    }
```

I run the pdflatex test.tex,and the content of the test.aux is

```
\relax 
\citation{Jag08}
\bibstyle{plainnat}
\bibdata{article}
```

The following is the content of the test.blg(using winedt)

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99dThe top-level auxiliary file: test.aux
The style file: plainnat.bst
I couldn't open database file article.bib
---line 4 of file test.aux
 : \bibdata{article
 :                 }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file test.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Jag08"
(There were 2 error messages)
```

Comment: Do you really need to use `\citep`? Try with `\cite` only.

Comment: sorry,i have corrected the typo,but it doesn't work.

Comment: It is not a typo. `\citep{}` comes with `natbib` package. Also, edit your post and show us the content of `.bib` file. It should have the data for entry `Jag08`.

Comment: I have edited the post.I am not sure if the path affects the compile,or the encoding,i have tried the ascii and UTF-8,but all failed.

Comment: i failed to run bibtex test,it gives the same wrong message as i mentioned.

Comment: Please, if you are going to edit your post, be careful to don't loose what we edited.

Comment: Compile your example once with pdflatex and then show the content of the test.aux-file.

Comment: sorry @Sigur.I am new here.I just click the edit and add some new information,i hope it will not affect what you edited.

Comment: Now click on the bibtex button. Then search in the folder the file test.blg and show its content (don't doubleclick on the file, open it with the winedt menu).

Comment: Do you see all file extensions?

Comment: Maybe some permission problem?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have edited my question and post the test.blg

Comment: Obviously bibtex can't find article.bib. So check **very** carefully the name, e.g. as Johannes suggested if the real file has an additional extension and is called article.bib.txt or something like this.

Comment: Or even trailing spaces, eg, `article .bib`

Comment: @Johannes_B Awesome.I forgot to show the all file extensions,and it works now after I modify the name from article.bib.tex to article.bib.

Comment: Finally!!! Have a nice work now.

Comment: It's kind of everyone who help me.Thank all of you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was due to a wrong file name and solved in comments